# Multiplication of multivariate power series

Tags: real-analysis, probability, multivariable-calculus, power-series

I am trying to solve the following problem. Let $X$ and $Y$ be bounded random variables such that $\mathbb E(X^kY^l) = \mathbb E X^k \mathbb E Y^l$ for all natural numbers $k,l$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

My thought is that because $X$ and $Y$ are bounded, and we have this factorization assumption, it is very natural to look at the joint characteristic function $\varphi_{X,Y}(s,t)$ and try to factor as $\varphi_X(s)\varphi_Y(t)$. Unfortunately, this is where I am stuck because I don't know how to multiply (multivariate) power series together. More specifically,

By boundedness, we can change the order of summation and expectation, so we have
$$\varphi_{X,Y}(s,t) = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\mathbb E[(isX+itY)^n]}{n!} = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} \mathbb E[(isX)^k]\mathbb E[(itY)^{n-k}]$$
As well as
$$\varphi_X(s)\varphi_Y(t) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\mathbb E[(isX)^n]}{n!}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\mathbb E[(itY)^n]}{n!}$$
And I want to say the two are equal. But I don't know how to multiply the latter two series together. In fact, I don't even know how we should define the multiplication of such multivariate power series.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{n!} \binom{n}{k} = \frac{k!}{(n - k)!}$ and $(\sum_{n} a_n)(\sum_{n} b_n) = \sum_{n} \sum_{m = 0}^n a_{m} b_{n-m}$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 so even though we are multiplying two univariate power series together to get a multivariate series, we should still use cauchy product?

Comment: Since $X,Y$ are bounded everything converges absolutely and we can exchange $\Bbb{E}$ and $\sum$ to get $
\Bbb{E}[e^{iux+ivy}]=
\Bbb{E}[\sum_{k\ge 0,n\ge 0} \frac{(-iux)^k}{k!}\frac{(-ivy)^n}{n!} ]=
\sum_{k\ge 0,n\ge 0}\Bbb{E}[ \frac{(-iux)^k}{k!}\frac{(-ivy)^n}{n!} ]$ $=
\sum_{k\ge 0,n\ge 0}\Bbb{E}[ \frac{(-iux)^k}{k!}]\Bbb{E}[\frac{(-ivy)^n}{n!} ]
=\Bbb{E}[e^{iux}]\Bbb{E}[e^{ivy}]$. The latter is the characteristic function of the product of two random variables following the law of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Two random variables have the same characterisitc function iff they follow the same distribution.

Comment: @reuns Ah so the point is that $\int f(x)\,d\mu_1(x) \int g(y)\,d\mu_2(y) = \int \int h(x,y)d\mu(x,y)$ where $\mu$ is the product measure and $h(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$.

Comment: @reuns If you put your comment as an answer I will accept it